# Does taking components with different $xy$-axes affect the result?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, coordinate-systems, free-body-diagram, string

I was solving a problem involving tension forces which is as follows:

> A small sphere of mass $m$ is suspended by a thread of length $l$. It is raised up to the height of suspension with thread fully stretched and released. Calculate the maximum tension in the thread.

[image: Diagram]

I drew this diagram. Here, magnitude of component $Tcosθ$ should be equal to weight $mg$ acting downwards. Hence,
$Tcos \theta = mg$ 
Therefore, $T=\frac{mg}{cos \theta}$

However, if I take the components of $mg$, changing the frame of reference:

[image]

Here, magnitude of $T$ can be equated to the component of $mg$.
$T=mgcos \theta$

Does taking components with a different frame of reference affect the output? Is there some related rule for taking components of a force vector?

Comment: Why do you think equality should hold in either of these cases when the object is accelerating both radially and tangentially?

Comment: According to me, These are the only forces acting in this case. So, can't their components be equated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reach to a paradox it indicates a mistake. I start the solution with correct equation and leave the rest for you

$\sum F_y = ma_y$

The object is moving in accelerating in y direction so $a_y$ is not zero. you assumed that it is zero. this yields,

$T cos \theta - mg = ma_y$

You should continue from here